# StatusListener in twitter4j not listening correctly

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

Trying to use StatusListener in twitter4j for listening to tweets from a particular user, and then respond to them.

But StatusListener seems to be unreliable. It seems to "hear" certain tweets but not others.

For instance when the user i am listening to sends a tweet, only sometimes does it get captured by my status listener, and it never gets captured if the tweet contains a photo for some reason, which is a problem because the user i want to listen to tweets photos every time!

This also seems to be the case for sending rgb codes like 0x234578

Is there something stopping status listener picking up these tweets?!

I am using the exact code from example number 9 at the bottom of this link:
http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sample():`
Starts listening on random sample of all public statuses.
This method is meant for getting a sample of tweets.

The example number 9 you mentioned is sample stream.
(http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterStream.html)

You have to use `UserStream`, not `SampleStream`

(Check method `user()`)

Check out this example:

https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/stream/PrintUserStream.java

Comment: hey man thanks it worked but I am not sure why, which part of the code does it specify which user you would like to listen to? I thought you needed to use a filter query for that

Comment: sorry now i've realised what was happening, when i used .user() method and UserStreamListener, it only listens to all the tweets in my timeline, but what i wanted it to do was to listen to only the tweets of one particular person, i was using FilterQuery, but it doesn't pick up on all their tweets, only some of them